# How can you remove homescreens on the Nexus 7 (2013)

Tags: nexus-7, home-screen, 4.4-kitkat

I have a Nexus 7 (2013) which comes with five homescreens, however I want to remove most of these but I'm unable to find an option to do so.

Most of the sites I've looked on so far suggest simply tapping and holding on the homescreen, but this prompts me to change my wallpaper.

How can you remove homescreens on the Nexus 7 (2013)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you have the [google-experience](/questions/tagged/google-experience) launcher? The one that comeswith the Nexus 5 and has integrated Google Now on the leftmost screen? It does not come with the Nexus 7 update, it is Nexus 5 exclusive. You CAN sideload it, but since you mention "Five Homescreens" you don't have it. You have the stock launcher.

If you are using the Nexus 7 'stock' launcher you cannot remove or add homescreens. You could install [Nova Launcher](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.teslacoilsw.launcher%26hl%3Den_GB&ei=igCrUuSgIOqp7AaDiYBo&usg=AFQjCNHfHh9A35Vz0HRwrcxulMt9MeDwpQ&bvm=bv.57967247,d.ZGU) or another third party launcher. You can easily add and remove screens on these, through pinch out and drag screen to the 'trash can' or 'X' icon.

**Specific to G.E.L:**

You simply remove all the shortcuts from the rightmost screen and it will automatically remove the screen itself. The reverse is true also, drag an icon out of the app drawer over the edge of the rightmost screen and a new one will be created.

**Side Loading GEL:**

[Phandroid 'How to' With links to the apk files](http://phandroid.com/2013/11/14/how-to-install-google-experience-launcher-with-ok-google-command/)

You can easily sideload GEL and you will only have one homescreen by default, and integrated Google Now. This should work on any Android 4.0+ Device. I have tested on 4.2.2 and 4.3 and 4.4 on Galaxy S4, Nexus 4 and HTC One.

Comment: @Kalina I've updated again with links on how to install the GEL on your device. Also Nova is a brilliant launcher, I've used it since my HTC Desire. Since they are both free, why not experiment with what you like? If you need anything else just let me know, if my answer was useful please condider accepting it!

Comment: Thanks for that - going through the process of installing GEL now!

Comment: Great, hope it works for you. Any issues let me know and we can sort it out. There are a few files to install to get it working. It worked first time on all my devices EXCEPT the Nexus 4, where it went very screwy. I got it working but reinstalling all the apks again a second time.

Comment: Yeah it's all up and running now, just re building my home screens! Much thanks

Answer (score 1):

No sideloading is necessary. Install the official "Google Now Launcher" from Google Play store and it will allow you to remove unused home screens (desktops) and enable the "OK Google" voice commands, among other things.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher

Answer (score -1):

I've figured this out and it's actually pretty easy:

1. Make sure one of the home screens is BLANK by removing all apps and widgets.
2. Then, PINCH TO ZOOM on the screen. This will bring up a collage of ALL the home screens.
3. Drag and drop the screen you would like into the 'Remove' trash bin.

Voila.

Comment: Pinching screens does not work on 4.2.2 stock launcher - whether or not the screen is empty. If it works for you, you may want to check your version...

Comment: This doesn't work for me on my Nexus 7 (with Android 5.0.2 loaded)...pinching has no effect.